# React, серверный рендеринг

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, ssr

Написал простую форму с material UI.
С npm start все работает.

Хочу генерировать на сервере, для чего использую такой код: https://pastebin.com/3dRZTXkK

Однако, стили не загружаются.

npm run build делал.

Comment: используйте next.js и не мучайтесь

Comment: Не подойдет, политика компании.

Comment: !!! PReact !!! https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli ||| https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/server-side-rendering/